# Vertical histogram in C language

Tags: arrays, c, histogram

I am able to print a histogram with a horizontal orientation with no problem. The exercise in my book also says to print one vertically. I have gotten the histogram to print, however the spacing for the *'s are off. I have attached a screenshot of the program. It is supposed to count the number of letters in a word, assign that number to an array with x value, then print a histogram, with the number of letters in a word then the array[wordlength]. In this case wordlength[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Vd2.png) would be 1 and get 1 star, then wordlength[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COuL5.png) = 2 so there should be two stars. It prints the two stars, just not in the correct spot.

[Sample Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COuL5.png)

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1            /* In a word */
#define OUT 0           /* Out of word */
#define MAXWORDLENGTH 10    /* Maximum word length */

main() {

    int c = 0, i = 0, j = 0, state = 0, letters = 0;
    int numstars = 0;               /* Length of graph */
    int ovflow = 0;                 /* Variable to catch words too long */
    int worldlengths[MAXWORDLENGTH];        /* Define array wordlengths */

    for (i = 1; i <= MAXWORDLENGTH; i++) {          /* Array to set  worldlengths to 0 */
        worldlengths[i] = 0;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
        state = OUT;            /* Out of word */
            if (letters > 0) {
                if (letters <= MAXWORDLENGTH) {
                    worldlengths[letters]++; /* Add 1 to the array value for letters length */
                } else {
                    ovflow++;
                }
            letters = 0;        /* Start counting new word */
            }                                               
        } else if (c == 'q') {
            break;
        } else if (state = OUT) {
            state = IN;                 /* In a word */
        letters += 1;                   /* Start of word */
        } else {
            letters++;                  /* Counting word length */
        }
    }

    for (i = MAXWORDLENGTH; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (j = MAXWORDLENGTH; j >= 1; j--)
        numstars = worldlengths[i];
        while (numstars > 0) {
            printf("  1\n");
            numstars -= 1;
        }
        if  (numstars == 0) {
//          printf("   ");
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= MAXWORDLENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%3d", i);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    for (i = 1; i <= MAXWORDLENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%3d", worldlengths[i]);
    }

}
```

any suggestions? I am attempting to learn C programming on my own and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Compile and enable Warning. for GCC use `gcc -Wall`. See warning and correct them.

Comment: `else if (state = OUT)` -> `else if (state == OUT)`

Comment: You either need to change the code to use array indices `0` to `MAXWORDLENGTH-1`, or increase the length of the `wordlengths` array by 1 to `int wordlengths[MAXWORDLENGTH+1]`.

Comment: Instead of writing a loop to initialize the array, just give it an initializer: `int wordlengths[MAXWORDLENGTH+1] = {0};`

Comment: The main printing loop can be something like `for (i = MAXWORDLENGTH; i >= 1; i--) {` `for (j = 1; j <= MAXWORDLENGTH; j++) {` `if (worldlengths[j] >= i)` `printf("  *");` `else` `printf("   ");` `}` `putchar('\n');` `}`. You could start `i` counting down from the actual maximum word length instead of counting down from `MAXWORDLENGTH`.

Comment: … (contd.) Actually, `i` should count down from the maximum `wordlengths[]` value, which you would need to determine before the loop.

Comment: Pedantic note: `main() { ... }` => `int main(void) { ... }`

Comment: @IanAbbott  had a good idea - here is how I would do it: https://onlinegdb.com/Tj6mW1JDP

Comment: @IanAbbot, thank you for your suggestions. Usings MAXWORDLENGTH -1 us a lot less confusing when used in the code. I was also able to get the code working by using your suggestion for the main printing loop. I also looked at the code you proposed, and it helped to grasp more of how it was printing so definitely a help! Barmar, your suggestions helped me to clean up the code a little bit so it looks a lot clearer.